# highlight / select text in numeric updown on enter

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Using VB.net for a windows form application.  I'm tired of always having to backspace the default '0' of a numeric updown control.  What I would like to do is have the value selected automatically on enter, so that I can just type over it.

I've tried this:

```
Private Sub updown1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles updown1.Enter
        Me.updown1.Select(0, updown1.Text.Length)

    End Sub
```

I've used a break point to verify that it does indeed run, but it doesn't seem to do anything.  What am I missing?

Comment: Your code is working fine, it's just that a mouse event fires after the Enter event and deselects the value immediately. To see what I mean, put that select code inside a updown1.MouseUp handler instead of updown1.Enter

Comment: Oh, ok. So it works when I tab into it.  I added the same code to the mouse up event like you suggested and that did it.  Please post this as the answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually selecting the value as intended, it is just being undone by a mouse event almost instantaneously. When you click to enter a NumericUpDown, the events fire in the following order:

1. Enter
2. GotFocus
3. MouseDown
4. Click
5. MouseUp

As you probably know, in controls with text fields the native behavior places the cursor wherever you've clicked inside the textbox. This is what's causing your problem. You have selected the text at Enter, but then a bunch of mouse events come along and undo all your hard work. The obvious solution is to just use the MouseUp event since that's at the end of the list, but MouseUp will fire for anywhere you click inside the control so you'll have to decide if that behavior is acceptable for you.

Comment: I added my code the mouseUp event of the NumericUpDown control as well as the Enter event (incase a user tabs into it).  It works great.  Thanks for that detailed explanation.